# Как создать свой dropDownList в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Как создать свой аналог yii\bootstrap4\Html\dropDownList в Yii2, что-бы он вызывался так же как обычно echo Html::dropDownList()?
То есть наверно надо переписать как то этот класс?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папку `widgets` вашего приложения положите файл с именем `Html.php` и приведённым ниже содержимым. Скорректируйте под свои потребности содержимое функции `dropDownList`:

```php
<?php

namespace app\widgets;

class Html extends \yii\bootstrap4\Html
{
    public static function dropDownList($name, $selection = null, $items = [], $options = [])
    {
        // Тут далее привожу стандартную генерацию дропдауна,
        // которую можно переписать под себя:
        if (!empty($options['multiple'])) {
            return static::listBox($name, $selection, $items, $options);
        }
        $options['name'] = $name;
        unset($options['unselect']);
        $selectOptions = static::renderSelectOptions($selection, $items, $options);

        return static::tag('select', "\n" . $selectOptions . "\n", $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: вот это я хотел увидеть! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: Посмотреть как реализован виджет изначальный, плюс посмотреть информацию о том, как пишутся виджеты и написать свой с нуля.

Пример создания:

- https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-widgets#creating-widgets
- http://www.webapplex.ru/sozdanie-sobstvennogo-vidzheta-v-yii-2.x
- https://webformyself.com/yii2-vidzhety/
- [https://tokmakov.msk.ru/blog/item/298#:~:text=Для%20создания%20виджета%20необходимо%20унаследовать,run()%20возвращает%20результат%20рендеринга](https://tokmakov.msk.ru/blog/item/298#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C,run()%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0).
- и так далее

Вариант 2: Отнаследоваться от текущего и внести свои правки в методы, свойства уже своего виджета, которые необходимо